# NextGEN Player Template Plugin

Tags: wordpress, nextgen-gallery

I use [NextGEN Player Template plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-player-template/), It is great plugin, but it shows portrait pictures in landscape mode. In other words, plugin takes the central part of the image and shows it as landscape orientation image.

And it is not the nextgen gallery issue, because [this another plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-scrollgallery/screenshots/) works with nextgen gallery too, but as we can see on third screenshot, it shows portrait images in portrait orientation. But this plugin has another problems, so I can't use it.

So, I need to see portrait orientation pictures in portrait orientation using NextGEN Player Template plugin. Cam anyone help?!

Answer (score 0):

Answer for last comment with picture:

My advice is to upload or see an example of the plugin. Then look at the source code with either chrome's or fire foxes "Inspector", they allow you to see each element and what they do with the page. Then find the DIV that is containing the image or Style that is editing the image itself. And then edit it accordingly.
 Though since this is a plugin there is probably a piece code that applies this to each div so you will need to track that back also. Or find someone who is willing to look inside all of your code. but perhaps research a little first and look into your code.

Ok i looked through your code there.
Try changing this

```
$('div.gv_panel').live('click', function() {
                $.fancybox({
                    autoScale: true,
```

to false.

Also these things apply to changing the image.

```
<div id="ngg_player_bg_changer" class="ngg-player-bg-changer" style="display: block;">

<div class="gv_panel" style="width: 564px; height: 400px; left: 0px;"><img style="visibility: visible; width: 601.504px; height: 400px; top: 0px; left: -19px; display: inline;" src="http://piotr-tokarczyk.pl/wp-content/gallery/player-1-2/g7.jpg"></img></div>
```

Holds all the different images i think

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That much files to create a gallery?

Comment: Before you edited your post you said what went wrong exactly. Something about the picture splitting?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: This plugin shows like this: http://www.picz.ge/img/s2/1303/1/1/107c456f210d.jpg but I need like this: http://www.picz.ge/img/s4/1303/1/b/b43577b52692.jpg  As I sad, plugin takes the central part of the portrait image and shows it as landscape orientation image.

Comment: demo is here http://piotr-tokarczyk.pl/nextgen-player-template/ everything is ok if you have only landscape orientation images but if you have portrait orientation images too, this is the problem. see attachments above please.

Comment: `$('div.gv_panel').live('click', function() {
                $.fancybox({
                    autoScale: true,` I can not find code like this in plugin files

Comment: Ok, the answer above is not useful. Anyone else?!

Comment: Its not usefull because you cant find the code?... ok closing this window.

Answer (score 0):

As the plugin is being actively developed, I would certainly suggest posting in http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/nextgen-player-template as Piotr seems to respond fairly quickly.